# 2 Column Width Issue during iteration LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-design-system, lwc-wire-adapter

I am not able to get a 2 column fields. I am trying to iterate over a list of 5 field to show all fields with 2 field each in one row.

```html
<div class="slds-grid">
    <div class="slds-col slds-size_2-of-2">
        <template for:each={theList} for:item="currentItem">
            <div key={currentItem}>
                <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                    <lightning-input type="text" label="Enter some text" 
                    class="slds-m-around_xx-small"></lightning-input>
                </div>
            </div>
        </template>
    </div>
</div>
```

```js
import { LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';

export default class CaseCreateUpdateCMP extends LightningElement {
  @track 
  theList = ['a','b','c','d'];
}
```

Comment: You need go apply the slds-grid as a container element before template for, and inside it add div with appropriate sizing slds classes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using the [SLDS grid](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/utilities/grid/) slightly in a wrong way.

The way it works is, you need to add `slds-grid` on parent element and child element should have `slds-col` classes respectively.

Remember, by default SLDS has 12 column grid. To get two columns, add `slds-size_1-of-2` to child elements.

To support multiple rows, you need to add `slds-wrap` to parent element with `slds-grid`.

Based on above information, below code will help in generating two columns:

```html
<div class="slds-grid slds-wrap">
    <template for:each={theList} for:item="currentItem">
        <div key={currentItem} class="slds-col slds-size_6-of-12">
            <div>
                <lightning-input type="text" label="Enter some text" 
                    class="slds-m-around_xx-small"></lightning-input>
            </div>
        </div>
    </template>
</div>
```

Check output in [playground](https://webcomponents.dev/preview/byu3B4w0s5r8y7EL3Hq8).

I'd recommend using [`lightning-layout`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-layout) base component as it makes working with grids easier.

Comment: 1 of 2 is the same as 6 of 12. You can use other ratios as outlined in the docs.

Comment: thanks @sfdcfox for correction, lately I use lightning-layout a lot, I need to revisit slds-grid, my knowledge on that is rusty.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. 